Facing route issue in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC
I am leaning ASP.NET Core MVC. I created a new CustomerController and then created a view. When I am trying to access it via localhost.../Customer/Index, I get this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Customer/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable originalLocations)
Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Customer/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable originalLocations)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I was expecting to see the markup in the Index.cshtml file of CustomerController.
Here is my code:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    namespace coreWebApplication.Controllers
    {
        public class CustomerController : Controller
        {
            // GET: /<controller>/
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Customer Management System.";
                return View();
            }
        }
    }

Here is markup of the Index.cshtml file
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>


Where is your Index.cshtml view located?

Are you sure that Index.cshtml exists in the Views/Customer/ directory? if you use Visual Studio as IDE you can right click on the Index method and click on AddView to create cshtml file in correct place

Hows your project structure and prpogram.cs looks like?

FYI .NET 7 is out of support - you should update to .NET 8.

Your folder under Views is misspelled Cusotmer instead of Customer ...... that's why the view can't be found

Hi @Biggs, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern.

The error message indicates that the Index.cshtml view file is not found in the expected locations. To resolve this, ensure the view file is correctly placed in the following directory structure:

Create the Customer folder under the Views folder if it doesn't exist.
Place the Index.cshtml file inside the Views/Customer folder.

The structure should look like this:
- Views
  - Customer
    - Index.cshtml
        <h1>Index</h1> 
        <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

Here is a checklist to ensure everything is set up correctly:

Correct File Structure:
 Views/Customer/Index.cshtml


Namespace and class names:


The controller class should be named CustomerController. The controller file should be placed in the Controllers folder.

View file:

The Index.cshtml file should be placed in the Views/Customer folder.
If everything is placed correctly and the issue persists, ensure that your project is rebuilt to reflect any recent changes.


I am leaning ASP.NET Core MVC. I created a new CustomerController and
then created a view. When I am trying to access it via
localhost.../Customer/Index, I get this error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
following locations were searched: /Views/Customer/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml




According to your error message and screenshot, your Index.cshtml file is not being found in the expected locations because, you have misspelled the view name which is causing the exceeption.
So if you rename the view according to the controller name it would resolve the issue.
As per your shared code you should have following directory for controller and view:

Make sure you have correct configuration in program.cs as well.
Controller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    namespace MVCProject.Controllers
    {
        public class CustomerController : Controller
        {
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Customer Management System.";
                return View();
            }
        }
    }

View:
Same as your code. However, when you would add view from controller, make sure you have added the Index view to the customer controller view folder accordingly. You should add like below:



Program.cs :
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();


if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Note: Please refer to this official document for additional sample and implementation. For MAC specific steps, check this document.

My index.cshtml file is in folder view/Customer/Index.cstml. The only different thing i did is in mac i was not able to add view the way you did in second image i added it using right click on Customer folder >> Add>> New file>>Razor View.

I think this causing the issue, so what you can do is, make sure the folder and files should be there what I shown you in the answer.

Also in MAC,  verify the properties of the file. In Visual Studio right-click on Index.cshtml, select "Properties", and ensure that "Build Action is set to "Content"

If you still having the problem please check this document.

As this part of error mentions:

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
following locations were searched: /Views/Customer/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

Your program can't find the Index in the locations that were searched.
Make sure you have created the Index view in the correct location:
It should be in this location: Views/Customer/Index.cshtml
